# How to test connection to server SSL port via proxy using Apache HttpClient 4.3.4?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-proxy

I'm trying to validate an SSL connection to an http server through a proxy server.  In my case, I have 4 pieces of information which are all supplied by the user, and which I'd like to validate explicitly: target host, target port, proxy host, proxy port. I'd prefer to NOT make an actual HTTP request in order to do this validation, since that requires 2 more pieces of information: a request method, and a path (ie. "GET /"). I'd really like to be able to use the HttpClient library because it supports NTLM proxy auth.

I suppose what I want is to get the response of a CONNECT request sent to the proxy server, as all it requires are the 4 pieces of information I have (plus any proxy creds).  However this seems to be an implicit request, the result of which is not available to the library client (unless it returns a 407 status code).  Is there some way to trigger the CONNECT request explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ProxyClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/ProxyClient.html) shipped with Apache HttpClient. It does precisely that.